# Custom select attribute of Customer not present in customer collection!

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, customer, custom, select

I have created an custom select attribute to the customer, Everything is working fine. the attribute save from register and checkout page.

But I wanted to display it in customer dashboard, When I say
`$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()`
My custom attribute is not in this $customer.
Here is my code

**upgrade script**

```
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'foundation', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'select',
    'label' => 'Foundation',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '0',
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
        'source'=> 'foundation/entity_foundation',
));
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<='))
{
      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
      $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
      $setup->addAttributeToSet('customer', $attrSetId, 'General', 'foundation');
}
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>='))
{
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'foundation')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'))
    ->save();
}
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Options for select box**

```
<?php
class Npm_Foundation_Model_Entity_Foundation extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $optionCollections = Mage::getModel('foundation/foundation')->getCollection();
        $options = array();
        foreach ($optionCollections as $foundations) {
            $options[] = array(
                'value' => $foundations->getData('foundation_id'),
                'label' => $foundations->getData('name_fr'));
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

**I am trying to get it in customer dashboard as below**

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

**Even I tried this also**

```
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
 $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($customerId);
```

**added config.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Npm_Foundation>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Npm_Foundation>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <foundation>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Npm_Foundation</module>
                    <frontName>foundation</frontName>
                </args>
            </foundation>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <foundation>
                    <file>foundation.xml</file>
                </foundation>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
         <fieldsets>
           <checkout_onepage_quote>
             <customer_foundation>
                 <to_customer>foundation</to_customer>
             </customer_school>
           </checkout_onepage_quote>
            <customer_account>
                <foundation>
                    <to_quote>customer_foundation</to_quote>
                </foundation>
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>
        <foundation_setup> 
            <setup>
                <module>Npm_Foundation_Model_Entity_Setup</module> 
                <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </foundation_setup>
        <models>
            <foundation>
                <class>Npm_Foundation_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>foundation_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </foundation>
            <foundation_mysql4>
                <class>Npm_Foundation_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <foundation>
                        <table>foundation</table>
                    </foundation>
                </entities>
            </foundation_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <foundation_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Npm_Foundation</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </foundation_setup>
            <foundation_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </foundation_write>
            <foundation_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </foundation_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <foundation>
                <class>Npm_Foundation_Block</class>
            </foundation>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <foundation>
                <class>Npm_Foundation_Helper</class>
            </foundation>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

But I am not getting the attribute in collection.

Its showing perfectly in admin customer edit section.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Can you save a value with a customer and check in the `customer_entity_int` table if the correct value is saved with all the correct relations? (entity ID, attribute ID etc)

Comment: @SanderMangel, Yes, I am getting the value in backend, When I try to edit from admin. I am getting select box with proper value.

Comment: ok so in the database it's saved correctly?

Comment: @SanderMangel, Yes

Comment: @SanderMangel, you are right, its not saving.. I have just created another customer and checked in back end its showing same for all customer. How can save it ?

Comment: I'v added an install script of my own below. This does work 100% sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29030/discussion-between-charlie-and-sander-mangel).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure what's wrong with your script but here's one that works (just used it myself)

```
$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'foundation',  array(
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'backend'       => '',
    'label'         => 'Foundation',
    'source'        => 'foundation/entity_foundation',
    'visible'       => 0,
    'is_visible'    => 0,
    'required'      => 0,
    'default'       => '0',
    'frontend'      => '',
    'unique'        => 0,
    'user_defined'  => 0,
));

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'foundation',
    '99'  //sort_order
);

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "foundation");
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
$attribute->save();
```

Comment: I am getting error like `Source model "foundation/entity_foundation" not found for attribute "foundation"`

Comment: @Charlie can you also post your config.xml

Comment: I have added the config.xml code

Comment: @Charlie can you delete the attribute (from `eav_attribute`) and try again with source = Npm_Foundation_Model_Entity_Foundation